# Why impala not showing all tables created by Hive

Tags: hive, impala, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have imported all tables using sqoop into a Hive database "sqoop_import" able to see all tables imported successfully as below :-

```
hive> use sqoop_import;
OK
Time taken: 0.026 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
categories
customers
departments
order_items
orders
products
Time taken: 0.025 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
hive>
```

But when I am trying the same from impala-shell or Hue using the same user, It's showing different results as below : -

```
[quickstart.cloudera:21000] > use sqoop_import;
Query: use sqoop_import
[quickstart.cloudera:21000] > show tables;
Query: show tables
+--------------+
| name         |
+--------------+
| customers    |
| customers_nk |
+--------------+
Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.01s
[quickstart.cloudera:21000] >
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Impala can't access all hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500221/impala-cant-access-all-hive-table)

Answer (score 2):

When you import a **new** table with `sqoop` to `hive`, in order to see it through Impala-Shell you should **INVALIDATE METADATA** of the specific table. So from the Impala-Shell run the following command   : ***impala-shell -d DB_NAME -q "INVALIDATE METADATA table_name";*** .

But if you append **new data files** to an existing table through `sqoop` you need to do REFRESH. So from the Impala-Shell run the following command: 
***impala-shell -d DB_NAME -q "REFRESH table_name";***.